# Jetty9 JSR356 WebSocket client - UpgradeException Issue

Tags: java, jetty-9, java-websocket

I have implemented jetty JSR356 client implementation only connecting to the web socket sever , first sending handshake connection to server , that is connected by server then server return response then we are getting error.
Jdk - 8
Jetty - 9.4.0.M0

I have done simple implementation suggested by jetty 356 web socket implementation - 
by using link - https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-websocket-example/

ERROR - ava.io.IOException: Connect failure
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connect(ClientContainer.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connectToServer(ClientContainer.java:184)
        at com.bilogicsys.hplus.cbwsi.ipi.client.controler.WebSocketClient.setupHandshakeConnection(WebSocketClient.java:105)
        at com.bilogicsys.hplus.cbwsi.ipi.client.controler.WebSocketClient.main(WebSocketClient.java:40)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Connection is upgrade, close (expected upgrade)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.validateResponse(UpgradeConnection.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.read(UpgradeConnection.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.onFillable(UpgradeConnection.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:269)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:202)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:269)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Also this error -

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connect failure
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connect(ClientContainer.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connectToServer(ClientContainer.java:184)
        at com.bilogicsys.hplus.cbwsi.ipi.client.wso.WebSocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebSocketClientEndpoint.java:60)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Didn't switch protocols, expected status <101>, but got <200>

Comment: Server team has confirmed that request url is ok , only issue is from client listener side.